# Chrome Keeps Sending GET for SSEs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Why does browser (Chrome) keep sending GET requests for SSE (Server-Sent Events)? Any idea why?

I only run the 'subscribeMe' function below **once** via clicking on button on the HTML page.

I understand that SSE works by only one GET is sent, and one 200 OK is received .. then with changes, server only pushes "data: ....." through the kept-open TCP HTTP/HTTPS connection.

```
const state = ['connecting', 'open', 'closed'];
let EPEvent;
function subscribeMe() {
  EPEvent = new EventSource(`/event/${window.sessionStorage.getItem("Token")}/EPRegistration`);
  EPEvent.onmessage = function (e) { console.log(state[this.readyState]); console.log(e); console.log(JSON.parse(e.data)) }
  EPEvent.onopen = function () { console.log(state[this.readyState]) }
}
```

```
GET /event/MTSE-960a8337-1f95-495c-a313-92659ba8ba5d/EPRegistration HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.2
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.1.2/manage
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2020 21:07:45 GMT
Server: Home SE
Content-Length: 14

data: null

GET /event/MTSE-960a8337-1f95-495c-a313-92659ba8ba5d/EPRegistration HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.2
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.1.2/manage
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2020 21:07:48 GMT
Server: Home SE
Content-Length: 14

data: null

GET /event/MTSE-960a8337-1f95-495c-a313-92659ba8ba5d/EPRegistration HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.2
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.1.2/manage
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2020 21:07:51 GMT
Server: Home SE
Content-Length: 14

data: null

GET /event/MTSE-960a8337-1f95-495c-a313-92659ba8ba5d/EPRegistration HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.2
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.1.2/manage
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2020 21:07:54 GMT
Server: Home SE
Content-Length: 14

data: null

GET /event/MTSE-960a8337-1f95-495c-a313-92659ba8ba5d/EPRegistration HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.2
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.1.2/manage
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2020 21:07:57 GMT
Server: Home SE
Content-Length: 14

data: null

GET /event/MTSE-960a8337-1f95-495c-a313-92659ba8ba5d/EPRegistration HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.2
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.1.2/manage
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2020 21:08:00 GMT
Server: Home SE
Content-Length: 14

data: null
```

Comment: It will periodically re-connect if it isn't receiving any data.  Are these GET request over some longer period of time?  Or immediate?

Comment: They are every 3 seconds .. exactly like the spec if the connection was failed, but that's not true. Connection never breaks from the Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

I should have not put 'Content-Length' in my response! .. This is a stream, Content-Length has no meaning.

Now, it is working fine.